# Scrape full articles from NYT archives in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the full text of articles from a New York Times archives search for an NLP task (search here: http://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/). I have legal access to all of the articles and can view them if I search the archives manually.

However, when I use urllib2, mechanize or requests to pull the HTML from the search results page, they are not pulling the relevant part of the code (links to the articles, number of hits) so that I can scrape the full articles. I am not getting an error message, the relevant sections, which are clearly visible in inspect element, are simply missing from the HTML that is pulled.

Because some of the articles are accessible to subscribers only, it occurred to me that this may be the problem and I have supplied my user credentials through Mechanize with the request, however this makes no difference in the code pulled.

There is a NYT API, however it does not give access to the full text of the articles, so it is useless to me for my purposes.

I assume that NYT has intentionally made scraping the page difficult, but I have a legal right to view all of these articles and so would appreciate any help with strategies that may help me get around the hurdles they have put up. I am new to web-scraping and am not sure where to start in figuring out this problem.

I tried pulling the HTML with all of the following, and got the same incomplete results each time:

```
url = 'http://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/#/India+%22united+states%22/from19810101to20150228/allresults/1/allauthors/relevance/Opinion/'
#trying urllib
import urllib
opener = urllib.FancyURLopener()
print opener.open(url).read()

#trying urllib2
import urllib2
request = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
print response.read()

#trying requests
import requests
print requests.get(url).text

#trying mechanize (impersonating browser)
import mechanize
import cookielib

br = mechanize.Browser()

cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

r = br.open(url)
print r.read()
```

Comment: Can you explain more about "I have a legal right to view all of these articles" - I doubt that this is true. Yes, it would be good to have a free and browsable record of the corporate media, for academia and research, but the only record I know of (other than each owner's website) is Lexis Nexis, for which a fee is presumably payable. What's your use case?

Comment: Additionally, if you are wanting to download a large amount of data, at the very least you should be inserting a pause between requests, so as not to accidentally perform a DoS attack on NYT servers.

Comment: I have a paid subscription to the New York Times, which allows me to read unlimited articles in the archive after 1980. I am not barraging them with requests, I am simply trying to read in the code from the search results page and ultimately I will be pulling the content of articles probably numbering only in the hundreds for an academic project. I do not believe there is anything shady about what I am trying to do.

Comment: OK. You could get in touch with them, in that case, and ask if there is a better way to do this. You may find that your "legal right" only extends as far as reading the articles on their website only. (Remember to use @halfer here to notify people of a reply, otherwise your response is likely to be missed).

Comment: "I will be pulling the content of articles probably numbering only in the hundreds" - put a few seconds pause in between each one, otherwise you _will_ be barraging them, even though it is not intentional.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a framework like Scrapy? This will give you a lot of power out of the box. For example, you will be able to retrieve those parts of the page you are interested in and discard the rest. I wrote a little example for dealing with Scrapy and ajax pages here: http://www.6020peaks.com/2014/12/how-to-scrape-hidden-web-data-with-python/
Maybe it can help you to get an idea of how Scrapy works.

Comment: Cool. Let us know your findings :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a tool like kimonolabs.com to scrape the articles. If you're having trouble using authentication, kimono has a built-in framework that allows you to enter and store your credentials, so that might help where you're otherwise limited with the NYT API. I made this NYT API using kimono that you can clone and use if you make a kimono account: https://www.kimonolabs.com/apis/c8i366xe

Here's a help center article for how to make an API behind a login: https://help.kimonolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/203275010-Fetch-data-from-behind-a-log-in-auth-API-

This article walks you through how to go through links to get the detailed page information: https://help.kimonolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/203438300-Source-URLs-to-crawl-from-another-kimono-API

Comment: just to note that kimonolabs.com does not exist anymore